Pandas-dev local setup is failing when building documentation
I am a newbie to open-source and I am fascinated by pandas, also their documentation is great and so is the support documnetation for newcomers.
I have been trying to work on a goodfirst issue here. However, I am facing issue in building documentation using
python make.py html, whenever I edit docstrings. FYI, for a fix, I edited, pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx. And, My documentation build failed. I even removed my edits, but the documentation build is failing still. I am not familiar with Sphinx and pandas uses this for documenation build.
Would highly appreciate if someone can help me figure why is this happening and what maybe the root-cause. Also, a fix for this would be immensely helpful.
The logs in the mentioned file, from screenshot:
# Platform:         darwin; (macOS-14.6-arm64-arm-64bit)
# Sphinx version:   8.0.2
# Python version:   3.10.15 (CPython)
# Docutils version: 0.21.2
# Jinja2 version:   3.1.4
# Pygments version: 2.18.0

# Last messages:
#   reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.WeekOfMonth.rule_code .. reference/plotting
#   
#   
#   reading sources... [ 95%]
#   reference/resampling .. whatsnew/v0.18.1
#   
#   
#   reading sources... [ 98%]
#   whatsnew/v0.19.0 .. whatsnew/v1.3.1
#   

# Loaded extensions:
#   sphinx.ext.mathjax (8.0.2)
#   alabaster (1.0.0)
#   sphinxcontrib.applehelp (2.0.0)
#   sphinxcontrib.devhelp (2.0.0)
#   sphinxcontrib.htmlhelp (2.1.0)
#   sphinxcontrib.serializinghtml (1.1.10)
#   sphinxcontrib.qthelp (2.0.0)
#   contributors (0.1)
#   IPython.sphinxext.ipython_directive (unknown version)
#   IPython.sphinxext.ipython_console_highlighting (unknown version)
#   matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive (3.9.2)
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc.preserve_defaults (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc.type_comment (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc.typehints (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.autosummary (8.0.2)
#   numpydoc (1.8.0)
#   sphinx_copybutton (0.5.2)
#   sphinx_design (0.6.1)
#   sphinx.ext.coverage (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.doctest (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.extlinks (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.ifconfig (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.intersphinx (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.linkcode (8.0.2)
#   sphinx.ext.todo (8.0.2)
#   nbsphinx (0.9.5)
#   pydata_sphinx_theme (unknown version)

# Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 337, in build_main
    app.build(args.force_all, args.filenames)
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 378, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 296, in build_update
    self.build(to_build,
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 317, in build
    updated_docnames = set(self.read())
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 422, in read
    self._read_parallel(docnames, nproc=self.app.parallel)
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 509, in _read_parallel
    tasks.join()
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/util/parallel.py", line 107, in join
    if not self._join_one():
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/util/parallel.py", line 125, in _join_one
    exc, logs, result = pipe.recv()
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/Users/swatisneha/miniforge3/envs/pandas-dev/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError

